# How to prevent GUI from hanging while allowing 2nd operation to be performed alongwith 1st operation in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Here I am explaining my problem statement in detail and the efforts I have put so far

A) **Problem Statement :** During printing if 'Stop Printing' pushbutton is pressed, the printing should stop at that moment!

B) **My Work :**

**1. StartPrinitng_Pressed** :

```
 void MainWindow :: on_StartPrinitng_Pressed()

{QSqlquery studentList;
 studentList("SELECT Name, address FROM class  WHERE Roll No = some       variable")

   while(studentList.next())
   {       
      Name=studentList.value(0).toString();   
      address=studentList.value(1).toString();   

      QTimer:: singleShot(1000,this,SLOT(StopNow()));   //calling stopNow function

      if(StopPrintingNow==0)
      {  //**   I am printing the fetched data (in a string)  by setting GPIO    pins  HIGH      **//  }


    }
 }
```

**2. StopPrinting_Pressed :**

```
 void MainWindow::on_StopPrinting_Pressed()
  {StopPrintingNow=1;}
```

**3. StopNow Function Declaration :**

```
 void MainWindow::StopNow() 
  {
   if(StopPrintingNow==1)
   {   //**  I have reset all serials ports; Break;   **// }
   else if(StopPrintingNow==0)
   { QTimer::singleShot(1000,this,SLOT(on_startPrinting_pressed())); }
  }
```

C) **Flow of program execution :** As and when "StartPrinting" pushbutton is pressed, the query shown in my question executes which fetches data from database and perform simultaneous printing.

D)**Problem Faced -**

1.GUI is getting hanged while printing, hence StopPrinting button doesn't   respond.

2. Qtimer is not calling "StopNow function " while printing (though I have called it at correct position)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2DyI.png)

Comment: Please pay attention to tagging the correct language. Qt is a set of C++ libraries, consequently your code shown is C++ as well -- fixed it right now :)

Comment: The problem is that all operations are done on the same thread, the QTimer trigger will be processed on the exec loop of the MainWindow, keeping that busy, so that the StopNow() will not be triggered (it will be run in the same exec loop). You will have to implement a thread, there are plenty of examples on SO and Google

Comment: When you have some heavy duty task going on in parallel to your GUI interaction it just screams multi-threading. Timers are great for triggering small changes but definitely not for controlling DB queries since (as already mentioned) timers' events need to be processed in the event loop of respective thread, which in your case is completely blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Handling of timers and button presses is both covered by the Qt event loop -- which is blocked while you are looping over that SQL query. You have two options:

1) Periodically dispatch events in your `while` loop.
This is as simple as

```
qApp->processEvents();
```

But you have to be careful, however: any events you trigger due to user interaction (or a timer) will block and your `while` loop will not run until the event is finished. In your case especially, you could end up running a second copy of your `on_StartPrinitng_Pressed` function.

2) Do the printing on a separate thread.
This involves some more code, but the gist of it is that you create a `SqlPrinter` object  with a `startPrinting` slot and `stopPrinting` slot. You then create a `QThread` and change its owner thread to that thread. Slot invocations will happen across the thread boundary and all will be fine.

```
class SqlPrinter : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    SqlPrinter(QObject* parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}
    public slots:
    void startPrinting();
    void stopPrinting();
};
```

In your main code, then do something like this, assuming that you have the two buttons named `MainWindow_StartButton` and `MainWindow_StopButton`:

```
QThread* printerThread = new QThread(qApp);
SqlPrinter* printer = new SqlPrinter;
printer->moveToThread(printerThread);
printerThread->start();
QObject::connect(MainWindow_StartButton, &QPushButton::clicked, printer, &SqlPrinter::StartPrinting);
QObject::connect(MainWindow_StopButton, &QPushButton::clicked, printer, &SqlPrinter::StopPrinting);
```

Don't forget to clean up `SqlPrinter` afterwards!